# Get 3rd level referrer url in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

How get 3rd level referrer URL using JavaScript. 
Suppose I have flow of visiting URL as

> a.com  ->  b.com  -> c.com -> d.com

Now I want to get URL of a.com from d.com. I have control on a.com and d.com not on b.com and c.com. How can we achieve this using JavaScript. Suggest some help.

Comment: Not really possible, without some agreement to transfer data between the 4 sites. If it were it would be a massive security problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, it is not possible. There must be agreement to transfer data between the sites. ;) :P

Comment: It is possible with the iframe use